# Qual a necessidade de se utilizar o sufixo "f" em uma constante numérica em C?

Tags: c, sintaxe, float, literal

É necessário adicionar `f` a um valor `float` dentro dos parâmetros de um `if`?

Exemplo:

```
if (a == 2.5f && a > 2.0f) {}
```

Comment: Bem vindo Eduardo. Embora não seja obrigatório inserir o 'f', é recomendado, pois o compilador interpretará o número como float.

Comment: Conforme [Constantes de ponto flutuante C](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/w9bk1wcy.aspx), sem o sufixo o valor será tratado como *double*. Há uma pergunta no SOen sobre isso também: [Suffix of “f” on float value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5026570/1452488)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nada tem a ver com `if`, é uma questão de escolher o [literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal) que quer usar.

Se quer que o número seja um `float` então deve usar o `f` sempre. Se não usar e tiver ponto decimal ele será por padrão um `double`. Este tipo possui 64 bits e o `float` tem 32 bits. Então com o sufixo `f` ou `F` ele ocupará menos espaço na memória, e claro, terá menos precisão.

Se o número for inteiro, ou seja, não tenha um ponto no literal, aí ele não será `double`, e muito menos `float`, a não ser que use um `f`.

Em ambos não haverá exatidão, como [já mostrado em pergunta anterior](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/325408/101) sua. Se for isso que deseja, não pode usar qualquer um deles. Precisa criar um mecanismo próprio, usar outra forma ou uma biblioteca que trate isso corretamente.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).